# Method receive List of more data types as parameter

Tags: java, list, casting, type-conversion, method-parameters

I have a method and as a parameter I send List.
The method looks like this:

```
public static void setSanctionTypes(List<QueueSueDTO> items) {

    for (QueueSueDTO dto : items) {

        StringBuffer sb = sanctionTypeRutine(dto.getRegres().getDebtors());

        String sanctionType = sb.toString();
        dto.setSanctionType(sanctionType);
    }
}
```

I need to use this method for different List data types parameters (for example `setSanctionTypes(List<QueuePaymentDTO> items);` etc.).
All clases I want to send as a parameter have method `getRegres()`, so content of `setSanctionTypes()` method is common and usable for all these classes I want to send to it.

If I do this

```
public static void setSanctionTypes(List<?> items) {

    for (Object dto : items) {

        StringBuffer sb = sanctionTypeRutine(dto.getRegres().getDebtors());

        String sanctionType = sb.toString();
        dto.setSanctionType(sanctionType);
    }
}
```

the dto of type Object doesn't know about getRegres(). I can cast to required type but it will be only one concrete type and it won't be usable for other parameters...

Is there way to resolve my problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: What about using Java's Reflection to find out the class of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have do define an interface which forces the classes to implement getRegres(). Then you implement this interface for all classes you need and use:

```
interface Interface {
  <type> getregres();
}

public static void setSanctionTypes(List<? extends Interface> items) {
```

Comment: It will also work if there is a class at the root of these classes which defines a method. An interface is nice to have, but not necessary for Generics to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an interface declaring your getRegres() method, and your list entries implement it:

```
public static void setSanctionTypes(List<? extends YourInterface> items) {

    for (YourInterface dto : items) {

        StringBuffer sb = sanctionTypeRutine(dto.getRegres().getDebtors());

        String sanctionType = sb.toString();
        dto.setSanctionType(sanctionType);
    }
}
```

For more information on "generics": http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The all types like `QueueSueDTO` have to implement a common interface. This way you declare your function as `setSanctionTypes(List<? extends QueueDTO> items)`.

The interface has to contain `getRegres` and any other functions you find relevant for all your classes, which are used as arguments to the `setSanctionTypes`:

```
interface QueueDTO
{
    RegresType getRegres();
    // maybe some more methods
}
```